# Do I need to call GC.KeepAlive(this) in my Dispose method?

Tags: .net, memory-management

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792660/is-gc-suppressfinalize-guaranteed) @Jon skeet referenced this [old blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/cbrumme/archive/2003/04/19/51365.aspx) by the authority Chris Brumme.

I was wondering, do I need to follow all calls to `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` with a `GC.KeepAlive(this)` to avoid weird race conditions where a finalizer can be invoked during the time a disposer is running in heavily multithreaded applications?

If so, can you come up with a sample program that exposes this bug?

Comment: I think whatever issue used to be here no longer, even if I try really hard to make it fail it does not ... http://gist.github.com/106190

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. `GC.KeepAlive` doesn't actually do anything; its purpose is to 'fool' the runtime into preventing a specific object from being garbage collected between the start of the method and the call to `GC.KeepAlive`.

Any method call will keep an object alive in this way: you could pass it to `Console.WriteLine`, call `ToString`, or even... `GC.SuppressFinalize`.

(Or as MSDN puts it:

> The KeepAlive method performs no operation and produces no side effects other than extending the lifetime of the object passed in as a parameter.)

Answer (score 3):

I was asked this recently by a colleague, and posted the answer on my blog, along with example code:

https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/08/q-if-dispose-calls-suppressfinalize-is.html

You may also be interested in other Disposable blog posts of mine, one of which explores when SuppressFinalize or KeepAlive() is required.

Answer (score 0):

Just curious, in what scenario would this give a problem?  Say the Dispose() method is past the point where it references any members of the object.  What could go wrong with the finalizer freeing the object?

Comment: nothing if the dispose method is coded correctly, im just curious about the way the CLR fuctions, also adding that extra line in your disposer isnt such a big deal ...